# Дополнительная память для окна

Tags: c, windows, winapi

При регистрации класса окна можно задать параметр `cbWndExtra` который будет показывать сколько дополнительно памяти выделить каждому окну

[WNDCLASSA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassa)

> cbWndExtra
>
> Type: int
>
> The number of extra bytes to allocate following the window instance. The system initializes the bytes to zero. If an application uses WNDCLASS to register a dialog box created by using the CLASS directive in the resource file, it must set this member to DLGWINDOWEXTRA.

[Здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-window-classes) в последнем абзаце сказано, что для доступа к этой памяти нужно использовать `SetWindowLong`

> The SetWindowLong function copies a value to the extra memory. The GetWindowLong function retrieves a value from the extra memory. The cbWndExtra member of the WNDCLASSEX structure specifies the amount of extra window memory to allocate. An application that does not use the memory must initialize cbWndExtra to zero.

Но из самого [описания](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlonga) `SetWindowLong` я не пойму как к этой памяти добраться. Все, что я вижу, так это констатация того факта, что память выделяется

> Reserve extra window memory by specifying a nonzero value in the cbWndExtra member of the WNDCLASSEX structure used with the RegisterClassEx function.

Так как получить указатель на эту память? Если я правильно понимаю, то GWL_USERDATA - это отдельный участок памяти размером `sizeof(LONG_PTR)` и он не зависит от `cbWndExtra`

Comment: Да, просто указывают 0 для получения указателя на экстра память. И если вы выделяет больше, то указывайте оффсет отличный от 0, т.е. больше чем 0.

Comment: @こきん Я не понял из вашего ответа откуда этот указатель получать и к чему применять смещение?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это можно сделать вызывая `GetWindowLongPtrW` - эта функция в качество второго параметра принимает смещение в блоке дополнительной памяти, выделенной для окна, либо одну из констант (со значением меньше нуля). Соответственно в первом случае в возвращаемом значении будут <размер указателя> байт, скопированных из этой дополнительный памяти. Ну а `SetWindowLongPtrW` соответственно пишет. Указатель на эту память получить нельзя.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что если у меня `cbWndExtra = 5`, то вызвав `GetWindowLong(wnd, 0)` я получу указатель из которого могу прочитать эти мои 5 байт? И соответственно вызвав `SetWindowLong(wnd, off, ptr)` `ptr` должен содержать cbWndExtra - off байт, которые будут скопированы в хранилище? Или я могу оперировать только последовательными кусками по `sizeof(LONG_PTR)` байт? Т.е. если мне нужно прочитать 8 байт на 32 разрядной системе, то я должен дважды вызвать `GetWindowLong(wnd, 0)`, `GetWindowLong(wnd, 4)`?

Comment: *"вызвав GetWindowLong(wnd, 0) я получу указатель"* - в ответе же прямо противоположное написано - *"Указатель на эту память получить нельзя"*, и вызвать надо `GetWindowLongPtrW`, а ни в коем случае не `GetWindowLong`. И да, для чтения 8 байт на 32-битной системе надо будет вызывать дважды. Если нужно получить именно указатель на блок, то его надо создать самостоятельно и сохранить / получить через `GWLP_USERDATA`.